# Tinder : How to send an automatic message?

Tags: message, bots

I would like after the "Match",
send a introduction message to all the matchs.
Do you know a way to send it easily?
( I use Bluestacks)

Thank by advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

simply pass the `session.send(<your message here>)` in `session.dialog('/')` which will be send message for all matches.